# Can I "swap" data between two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a csv file that comes from somewhere else, and the process I'm using is to either drop or truncate a table, then import the csv this

```
BULK INSERT DataExtraction_BasicLoan
    FROM 'Filename'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        TABLOCK
    )
```

This takes about 40 seconds. I'm wondering what I can do to mitigate the chance that someone will get no results during that 40 second interval. I was thinking maybe I could put it into a second table and just swap the names of the tables? Does that seem plausible? It would probably be easier to use a temp table but I'm not sure what that would look like.

Comment: [Kendra Little suggests partition switching](https://www.littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/) rather than my old school approach (see [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll read these. I figured this wasn't something unique but I didn't know what to search for.